# Java Servlet header implicit object

Tags: java, servlets

I've been working with Java servlets and noticed a peculiar problem in the following code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String url = "/Display.jsp";

    CSVFileOperations csvfo = new CSVFileOperations();

    String header = csvfo.getHeaders().remove();
    System.out.println(header);

    request.setAttribute("header", header);

    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, 
    response);
```

In particular, this line:

> request.setAttribute("header", header);

I set both the String identifier and the variable name as the same. When I call this variable in my .jsp file via `${header}`, I get the following output:

```
{accept-language=en-US, ua-cpu=AMD64, 
cookie=JSESSIONID=1E0C2784352A46D6EFDE0F8A522F4, host=localhost:8080, 
connection=Keep-Alive, cache-control=no-cache, accept-encoding=gzip, 
deflate, accept=image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms- 
application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*, user- 
agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like 
Gecko}
```

However, when I change the String identifier from `"header"` to `"head"` and call  `${head}` in the .jsp page, I get the expected output.

My question is, **what is going on here?**

Comment: First, you are not correct about reflection and the servlet / jsp API. JSP(s) are compiled to servlet(s). Second, the variable `${header}` is already defined to return the http header sent from the client, which is what you are seeing there; notice the `String` "agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0" is from the browser. I can see you are using Windows 10; running on 64-bit hardware, using [Internet Explorer 11](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11s-many-user-agent-strings/).

Comment: @Elliot Frisch - I edited my post. I completely forgot .jsp pages are converted back to servlets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP defines some [**implicit objects**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html), to allow the JSP access to the same information that the Servlet code has.

These implicit objects are assigned at *page* scope, so they supersede any request attribute of the same name.

Solutions:

1. Don't use a request attribute name that matches an implicit object name.
2. Qualify access with `requestScope`, i.e. use `${requestScope.header}` in your JSP.

I'd recommend option 1.

> The JSP expression language defines a set of implicit objects:
>
> - `pageContext`: The context for the JSP page. Provides access to various objects including:
> - `servletContext`: The context for the JSP page’s servlet and any web components contained in the same application. See Accessing the Web Context.
> - `session`: The session object for the client. See Maintaining Client State.
> - `request`: The request triggering the execution of the JSP page. See Getting Information from Requests.
> - `response`: The response returned by the JSP page. See Constructing Responses.
>
> In addition, several implicit objects are available that allow easy access to the following objects:
>
> - `param`: Maps a request parameter name to a single value
> - `paramValues`: Maps a request parameter name to an array of values
> - **`header`**: Maps a request header name to a single value
> - `headerValues`: Maps a request header name to an array of values
> - `cookie`: Maps a cookie name to a single cookie
> - `initParam`: Maps a context initialization parameter name to a single value
>
> Finally, there are objects that allow access to the various scoped variables described in Using Scope Objects.
>
> - `pageScope`: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
> - `requestScope`: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
> - `sessionScope`: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
> - `applicationScope`: Maps application-scoped variable names to their values

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I suppose using header as an identifier was a poor choice.